# Index Match with Multiple Criteria & Substring Within String

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have the multiple criteria stuff down but the problem comes when attempting to match a substring within a string.

This formula that index/matches with a substring finding in a string works well.

```
=INDEX(ProdRedmineData[Ticket '#],MATCH("*"&[@MO]&"*",ProdRedmineData[MO],0))
```

But I cannot translate that to multiple criteria using the array format. The formula below does not seem to work...

```
{=INDEX(ProdRedmineData[Ticket '#],MATCH(1,("*"&[@MO]&"*"=ProdRedmineData[MO]) 
 *([@Config]=ProdRedmineData[Config]),0))}
```

[image]

The Column titled "Redmine #" is where the formula is located.

[image]

This table is the ProdRedmineData Table

Update: No fix yet at this time. I might be able to come up with a workaround of separating the 2nd table by the MO but that would require more time than I would like and the size would increase quite a bit.

Comment: Can you share sample data with inputs and expected outputs

Comment: Working on adding pictures now!

Comment: `"*"&MasterPRSTData[@MO]&"*"=ProdRedmineData[MO]` does not work.  You will want to use `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MasterPRSTData[@MO],ProdRedmineData[MO]))`

Comment: I was actually already doing that. Forgot to add that in initially. It is now shown correctly